# Bash - How to get strings surrounding substring in file

Tags: bash, shell

If I have a file with for example the line:

```
hai hello test hey hi
```

I then want to search for the lines with `test` in it, and return the two surrounding strings `hello` and `hey`.

I can get the lines in which the search word is found using:

```
grep "test" $file"
```

But I can't figure out how to only get the two surrounding strings and do further things with the strings

Comment: Specify: *and do further things with the strings*

Comment: With *strings* you mean *words*, right? The `o` at the end of `hello`, the space between `hello` and `test`, or even the empty string are strings too,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grep -o` you can print only that part of a line that matches the given regex. Now you need a regex that matches `test` *and* its two surrounding words. To come up with something like this you have to know what a *word* is supposed to be, that is, what makes it different from any other string. Here we go with: *"A word is a sequence of letters A-Za-z surrounded by anything that is not a letter"*

```
grep -Eo '[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z]+test[^A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+' file
```

Note that this ignores all `test` that are not surrounded be words, for instance the lines `test`, `test b`, and `a test`. If you give a more detailed explanation of what you need I can adjust the regex.